# Does urllib2 support server which returns both basic and digest authentication

Tags: python, urllib2, http-authentication

I'm using urllib2.
I have problem to login a server which returns both basic and digest authentication.

it returns :

```
WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="rets@aus.rets.interealty.com",nonce="c068c3d7d30cc0cd80db4d1c599e6d54",opaque="e75078c8-a825-474b-b101-f8ca2d1627ca",qop="auth"
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="rets@aus.rets.interealty.com"
```

here's my code :

```
passman = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
passman.add_password(realm=None, uri='http://aus.rets.interealty.com', user='user', passwd='pwd')
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPDigestAuthHandler(passman))

urllib2.install_opener(opener)

retsRequest= urllib2.Request('http://aus.rets.interealty.com/Login.asmx/Login')
retsRequest.add_header("User-Agent", 'userAgent')
retsRequest.add_header("RETS-Version",'retsVersion')

response=urllib2.urlopen(retsRequest)

print response.read()
```

I can login this server using IE and it seems IE uses digest authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I have not encountered the same problem, but was once surprised to realize that the opener with `urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler` makes actually two requests instead of one: the first without authentification and then as fallback the second with the authentification.

That is it may turn out that your case would require three requests, where the third request might forget the authentification from the second - one should check.

And you should probably add both: `urllib2.HTTPDigestAuthHandler`, and `urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler` to the opener.

Comment: I've tried adding both urllib2.HTTPDigestAuthHandler and urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler, it doesn't work.
I can login this server by simply adding a header :    
    base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (retsUSER, retsPWD))[:-1]
    retsRequest.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)
So i decide to choose this way.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I have time to review this question, I think I found the answer.It's kind of a bug of python urllib2. In urllib2:

```
class AbstractDigestAuthHandler:
    def http_error_auth_reqed(self, auth_header, host, req, headers):
        authreq = headers.get(auth_header, None)
        if self.retried > 5:
            # Don't fail endlessly - if we failed once, we'll probably
            # fail a second time. Hm. Unless the Password Manager is
            # prompting for the information. Crap. This isn't great
            # but it's better than the current 'repeat until recursion
            # depth exceeded' approach <wink>
            raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), 401, "digest auth failed",
                            headers, None)
        else:
            self.retried += 1
        if authreq:
            scheme = authreq.split()[0]
            if scheme.lower() == 'digest':
                return self.retry_http_digest_auth(req, authreq)
```

Here authreq is :

```
Basic realm="rets@tra.rets.interealty.com", Digest realm="rets@tra.rets.interealty.com",nonce="512f616ed13813817feddb4fb0ce9e2d",opaque="84f5e814-d38a-44b4-8239-3f5be6ee3153",qop="auth"
```

authreq.split()[0] will be "Basic", it will never be "digest", so urllib2 will not do the second request in a digest authentication.

Basicly urllib2 assumes only one authentication can be in the first 401 response header. Unfortunately this server returns two types of authentication.

To solve this problem, either you can use the basic authentication or you can use other library like 'requests'.